# Why is Parallel.For taking the same time as normal for loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a problem. I want to use the Parallel.For loop which should cost  15 seconds.

For example:

```
AForge.Parallel.For(0, 2, delegate(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        resim.Morphology(MorphologyMethod.HitAndMiss, kernel1);
        resim.Write("sag.bmp");
        label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
    else if (i == 1)
    {
        resim2.Morphology(MorphologyMethod.HitAndMiss, kernel2);
        resim2.Write("sol.bmp");
        label3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
});
```

If I don't use parallel for, it will cost 30 seconds. If I use parallel for ,it should cost 15 seconds, but Parallel.For doesn't work .When I use parallel for it costed 30 seconds. I don't understand.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you can not access a GUI control (label2 and lable3) from a non-UI thread.  This generates an `Exception`.  Try removing the two lines and see what happens.

Also, since AForge is CPU intensive, you need to be testing on a machine that has multiple CPUs.

**Update thanks to Aron**

This will force the tasks to run on separate threads.

```
var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    resim.Morphology(MorphologyMethod.HitAndMiss, kernel1);
    resim.Write("sag.bmp");
});
var t2 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    resim.Morphology(MorphologyMethod.HitAndMiss, kernel2);
    resim.Write("sol.bmp");
});
Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { t1, t2 });
```

Comment: In fact this is one of the few cases I would advocate for using `Task.Run()`.

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure this answers the OP's question, as i'm not even sure he knows what he's asking.

Comment: @Aron, I agree.  I was just trying to get existing code to work.  Why don't u post your method.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, as my daughter would say `he he` (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hehe)

Comment: I removed two labels. Result is same Also I tested on a machine that has multiple CPUs.

Comment: As @Aron hinted at, try two `Task.Run()`.  If he does provide an answer, I'll create one in 15 minutes.

Comment: @RichardSchneider I don't know AForge enough to complete the code. Go ahead.

Comment: Task.Run queues the work on the ThreadPool, so there is no guarantee it will run on separate threads or in parallel, since that is controlled by the scheduler, depends on thread pool size etc. So i do not agree it will "force" the tasks to run on separate threads, but in ideal conditions it should run on separate threads.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539(v=vs.110).aspx) page for **Parallel.For**:

> Executes a for (For in Visual Basic) loop in which iterations may run
>   in parallel.

The key word is **may**, which actually means that it is not guaranteed to run in parallel, and even if it was running in parallel there is no guarantee the performance would be better compared to the plain sequential code, so your expectation for Parallel to run 2x faster is just wrong.

In addition, you are updating UI controls from a Parallel loop which is running on the UI thread, which is not a good idea. Here is another excerpt from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Attempting to update UI controls from within a parallel loop that is executing on the UI thread can lead to state corruption, exceptions, delayed updates, and even deadlocks, depending on how the UI update is invoked.